# Script to delete files that contain more than a given number of bytes on Centos7

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, files

I need a script that deletes files. I give the names of the files, and if the file size is more than the given size it should be deleted, if not then nothing should happen.

I tried something like this but I couldn't figure out how I can compare the sizes

```
se=$1 
file1=$2 file2=$3 
wc -c $2 $3 
for file in $2 $3
do 
fi [ $2 -gt $1]
then  rm $1
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a script. There exists a standard command-line tool, called `find`, which can do exactly what you want. For example, in order to delete all files under `/tmp` that are larger than 1 gigabyte, first for safety, run:

```
find /tmp -size +1G
```

Then, once you are sure that you aren't going to delete anything unwanted:

```
find /tmp -size +1G -delete
```

Note that in your question you are making a common error, that you aren't quoting your shell variables, so if any of your files have embedded spaces, you'll get unwelcome results. Using the `find` command with its own internal `-delete` command avoids that.

As usual, the `man` page will give you the complete documentation for this very powerful command.

Note that by default the command operates on all sub-directories of the given path. In order to limit the operation, you can use `-maxdepth` option.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors or inconsistencies in your script:

1. You declare some variables, but you don't use them;
2. You use `wc -c $2 $3`, but you don't assign the result to any variable, so the result is only printed in the terminal, but you can't use it in your script.
3. You wrote `fi [ $2 -gt $1]`. The first word should have been `if`, not `fi`. The pattern is `if [condition]; then [do something]; fi`.
4. Because of the point 2. of this answer, even if you had written `if [ $2 -gt $1]; then`, inside `$2` and `$1` there are only the filenames, so you're not comparing their size, but their names.

I think you should try some bash scripting tutorial, here we don't write scripts for you, we solve your problems. Here there are some links you can find useful: a [bash scripting tutorial for beginners](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners) and a [bash scripting tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial)

Comment: I'm still learning scripting , thank you allot for the tutorial